# I m trying to convert the pixels which is painted black to another color but ı got an error l

Tags: python, numpy

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('images1.png')

ss=[]

for x in range (0,260,1):

    for y in range(0,190,1):

        if image[y,x]==[0,0,0]:

            image[y,x]=[0,255,162]

cv2.imshow("image",image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Error:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
> Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow bw

Comment: Please share your input image if you would like some assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this fast, you don't want to do this with a loop – instead, use [`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) to get a mask "image" of pixels matching your color, then paint them all black with a Numpy broadcast assignment:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.png')
src_color = (0, 0, 0)

# Compute matching pixels
mask = cv2.inRange(image, src_color, src_color)

# Replace pixels where the mask is nonzero
image[mask > 0] = [0, 255, 162]

cv2.imshow("image", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This turns this:
[image]
into this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to compare an array with another when you call img[y,x]==[0,0,0] you got a vector of 3 logicals (supose [True,True,True] or any other variation). You have to compress this to an unique logical: you can use .all() to that (black means that the cannel  red ==0 , the blue==0 and green==0, so you need that the 3 vals to be True to enter the if)

so the solution will be to replace

```
  if image[y,x]==[0,0,0]:
```

with

```
  if (image[y,x]==[0,0,0]).all():
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ı got logic right now wish you best

Comment: @DenizÇakar sorry I didn't understand, did it worked?

Comment: It works very well.